# Rotation of multiple rotated cuboids

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have no strong mathematical background and coming from c++ programming. Sorry if my question will be unclear. I am generating the cuboids which are rotated at each other top point, see the picture:
https://ibb.co/XsDTTm7

The rotations of each cuboid  are described as AxisAngle structures {x, y, z, theta}.I can also using  conversions to the quaternions if needed.

And now I need to rotate the whole structure according its origin points, let's say 45 degrees. I cannot simply multiply the existing rotations by new one as the original structure will be lost. Only the initial cuboid should be rotated by 45 degrees, and the rest of them must must remain in the same structure but rotated as a whole. So I guess the directions of rotation vectors must be recalculated. However, I have no clue currently how to start it or where to look for the information. Could someone please advise?

Comment: How do you position cuboids? Do you have the ability to work with transformations (transformation matrices) or you have to calculate the translations separately?

Comment: hello, thank you for your attention.  the cuboids are created like that: the rotation axis and angle is selected randomly. the first one is chosen. Then the center of  top face is calculated and selected as a position for a new cube.